# Can compile C++ files using Clang in Powershell but I cannot run the .exe

Tags: powershell, compiler-errors, clang, windows-11

I am trying to test a C++ file for a project I am building.
I opened up power shell in the directory I was working in. Compiled my file using clang

```
clang -o hello_world hello_world.cpp
```

the file compiled. however when I go to run the .exe file

```
./hello_world
```

Powershell doesn't execute the program but pulls up text editors to view the machine code.

How can I fix my powershell and terminal to run the .exe

Comment: Does the file exist when looking in Windows Explorer? Does it have the .exe extension? You're not specifying an extension in `-o hello_world`.

Comment: Binary executables require an `.exe` filename extension on Windows, so try `clang -o hello_world.exe hello_world.cpp`

Comment: Thanks, Adding .exe file extension to the compilation allowed me to run the file in powershell.